# Non obtrusive Javascript popup

Tags: javascript, html, popup, alert

How can one create a popup/alert in javascript that shows the information and at the same time allowsthe user to input data in the input fields of the HTML form.

Comment: What have you looked for? 1) There are *many* different "popup" and "tooltip" libraries for JavaScript 2) This post poses a *Task* and not a single *Specific Question*. After looking for things in #1, there might be a [better] question for #2.

Comment: You can create a `div` with an higher `z-index` and place it wherever you want. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This could not be accomplished with any predefined function, like `alert()`. This would recuire either you coding one (wouldn't be so hard, just a div with a bit of CSS styling), or using something like a jQuery/JavaScript function (there are a lot of so-called lightbox plugins available).

Comment: are you trying to allow the user to enter data in the in the popup for in the site itself. Also would you want to do it yourself or use a library

Comment: [jQuery Ui](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) is here to help you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rwVGt/

HTML:

```
<p>testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtest ingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingt
  estingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingt estingtestingtestingtestingtestingtesting</p>
<input
type="button" value="click for popup" onClick="popup()" />
```

CSS:

```
#pop
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var popup = document.createElement("div");
  var text = document.createTextNode("blah blah blah");
  popup.appendChild(text);
  popup.style.visibility = "hidden";
  popup.id = "pop";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(popup);
};

window.popup = function () {
  var pop = document.getElementById("pop");
  pop.style.visibility = "visible";
  window.setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("pop").style.visibility="hidden";},1000);
};
```

Comment: oughta use `addEventListener` instead of assigning to handler attributes, and `document.body` would be a bit easier to read